# Is using cpp macros as scripting language a bad thing?

Tags: c++, macros, performance

)

well this is my situationI'm working on Cpp/Qt project where we have some predefined routines to allocate array memory

```
ex:
alloc2(n1, n2, s) return a pointer to a 2d (n1*n2) array of elements of size "s"
```

if allocation fails it will return a NULL

I wrote some macros to make an easy call to those routines and in case memory allocation fails it will write an error message and exit the current block of code.

```
#define ALLOC2(p, n1, n2, size)   if(NULL == (p=alloc2((n1), (n2), (size)))){   \
                                    TheConsole->Message(QString("ERROR MSG"));  \
                                    return false;                               \
                                  }
```

of course, the macros have to be called properly, and n1, n2 have to be only of int type

but one of the advantages here is that I don't have to pass a the pointer of "TheConsole" as macros may work as "scripting" language; it will replace blindly "ALLOC2(p, n1, n2, size)" by its definition.

My question is:
I have 144 macro like this different types and dimensions and each is called in the code handers of times, is this way of using macros will cause some "Code bloat" or slow in some way my program??

Comment: Yes. *the macros have to be called properly* pretty much speaks for that solution.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is getting downvoted so much. I mean - the idea is wrong here, but its both clear and useful for other people, so they can learn why this is a bad approach.

Comment: Must be because of poor formatting. But I did not downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than making debugging difficult and coding confusing, I cannot understand a sane reason for using macros for such tasks, especially if there are 144 like these.

**EDIT:** After reading the OP's comments I believe that he has some misconception of macros.
Macros are nothing but abbreviation of code. For example `WYSIWYG` is an abbreviation of `What You See Is What You Get`. Now when you define this as a macro, you just have to type `WYSIWYG` instead of `What You See Is What You Get`. This saves a lot of typing, yes, but using functions is a much better alternative.

When a compiler sees a macro, it simply **replaces** your abbreviation with the full form; similar to `Find and Replace`. Obviously there is *no effect on the performance of  your software, but rather your compile time is increased*.

Comment: Many thanks @cool_Coder 
this answers exactly my question "there is no effect on the performance of your software, but rather your compile time is increased." discussion is always good :)

Comment: I am glad that I could help you!

Answer (score 3):

> we have some predefined routines

You use *functions* to encapsulate those.

> in case memory allocation fails it will write an error message and exit the current block of code.

You throw an exception for that. Also, you shouldn't allocate memory manually most of the time.

> of course, the macros have to be called properly

Which makes them unsafe.

> but one of the advantages here is that I don't have to pass a the pointer of "TheConsole"

Which is hardly an advantage, considering C++'s primitives for sharing state.

Comment: Yes certainly throwing exception is the way to do it....
but here the code is already written (by some other people) and it's pretty large (about 500 Mb of ascii files containing the code) so to implement exception handling becomes a nightmare, at least for me:(

so I had to find another way to avoid crushing in case memory allocation fails and instead write a msg into theConsole.

I know macros are not type safe, but if used correctly they are great
I know they make debugging difficult.

Can you think of a better way?

Comment: @Gibnem Pardon me, what exactly is "great" about them? They are not typesafe and hard to debug. Any positives? As for the legacy codebase... well, fail.

Comment: All of what you've said makes sense for me, except, why macros aren't great is used correctly and if they could solve your problem? I'm not a master programer but if macros are there they have to be used no? I also use macros many times for defining constants and for conditional compilation... do you think it's also not a good idea?

Comment: @Gibnem "If macros are there they have to be used" - **No.** Using them for conditional compilation is OK, but certainly not for constants; there's `const` keyword you can use for that. The fact that something used correctly can solve your problem doesn't mean anything. Sooner or later the code will have to be changed and then you're left with a pile of unfixable mess like yours.